# Find the modular node of a linked list from the end. If possible, do it in a single pass?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, c++14

Given a singly linked list, how do you find the first from the end whose n%k==0, where n is the number of elements in the list & k is an integer constant? If n= 19 and k =3, then we should return 16th node. Is it possible to do it in a single pass?

Comment: If `n= 9` and `k =3`, then there is no 16th node. There are 9 nodes total, by definition of `n`. Further, the expression `n % k` is a constant that doesn't depend on the node, so it's not clear what you mean by "node whose  `n%k==0`". Either `n%k` equals zero, or it doesn't.

Comment: @Charu Agarwal question is not clear, please modify it and we will be able to help you out.

Comment: Hey! I am so sorry. I missed the 1 in 19. It's actually 19. Can you please help me out now?

Comment: This is still unclear. why is n is 19 and k is 3 does it make the 16th node the one? 19%3 is 1, not 0?

Answer (score 4):

I think there is some mistake in this question means from last n%k==0 is 17th Node not 16th Node.

Check this:
1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9->10->11->12->13->14->15->16->17->18->19

Start counting: 19 is at 1st position from end. So 1%3 !=0

18 is at 2nd position from end. So 2%3 !=0

17 is at 3rd position from end. So 3%3 ==0.

**17 is a n%k==0 Node from end.**

Yes, we can find this in a single pass. For this take two reference one is **head** and other is **mod_Node**. First move your **head** reference till k position after that start moving your **mod_Node** with **head** once your **head** reached at null then at that time your **mod_Node** pointing to **"n%k==0 from end"** Node.

```
public Node modNode(Node head,int k)
{
    Node mod_Node=head;

    int i=0;

    while(head!=null)
    {
        if(i<k)
            i++;        
        else
           mod_Node=mod_Node.next;   
        head=head.next;
    }
    return mod_Node;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Question is just a different way of asking for the **k<sup>th</sup>** element from the **end** of the linked list. Since the **first** element from the **end** for which we have **n%k=0** , has to be the **k<sup>th</sup>** element (considering **1-based** indexing of nodes).
Suppose total number of nodes are **N**(we don't know **N**). So **k<sup>th</sup>** from end means **(N-k+1)<sup>th</sup>** from beginning.
 Now for doing it in single pass, we take two pointer approach.

- Suppose we have two pointers ***fast*** and ***slow***.
- Initially **both points to head** node of the list.
- ***slow*** starts moving only after ***fast*** has made **k-1** moves i.e ***slow*** moves only after ***fast*** points to the **kth** element from the beginning.
- From there **both** move forward until ***fast*** reaches the end of the list.

**NOTE:** *At any point of time both the pointers move one node at a time.*

 What this means is once ***fast*** is at the **k<sup>th</sup>** node from beginning, it has **(N-k)** moves to reach the last node. Which means the ***slow*** pointer will too be moving **(N-k)** moves from there and will reach the **(N-k+1)<sup>th</sup>** node.

***A bit of intuition***: To reach the **k<sup>th</sup>** **node** from beginning we need **(k-1)moves**, so to reach
 **(N-k+1)<sup>th</sup> node** from beginning we need **(N-k+1-1)=(N-k)** **moves**. And after moving ***fast*** to **k<sup>th</sup>** **node** we are left with **(N-k) moves**.

**Now the code:**

```
//Our structure:
struct Node{
   int data;
   Node* next;
};

//Function to return the kth node from end.
    Node* kthNodeFromEnd(Node* head,int k){
        Node *fast,*slow; 
        int l=1;
        fast=slow=head;
        while(fast->next!=NULL){
            fast=fast->next;
            l++;
           // Move slow only after fast has reached kth node.
           // From there both moves together.
            if(l>k){
                slow=slow->next;
            }
        }
        return slow;
    }
```

***Question Clarification:***
Now for **n=19** and **k=3**, if we number the nodes from the **beginning** using **1-based** index we will get **17th** node as our answer, but if we number the nodes using **0-based** index, we will get **16th** node as the answer. **May be** the source of your question had **0-based** indexing of nodes.
**Note**: ***"n"*** is defined as the number of nodes in the list, we can number the nodes in any way. Say for **n=1** , we have **0th** node.For **n=2**, we have **0th,1st** node and so on with us.

Answer (score 0):

Same as finding kth node from the end.

1. Take 2 pointers p and q and make them both point to head.
2. Move p 'k-1' times.
3. Only after then move p and q by 1 step till p becomes the last node.
   (i.e. till p->next becomes NULL)
4. By the time p reaches the last node q will point to the kth node from the end.

**Logic is we are maintaining the distance between between q and p = distance between kth node and last node.**

Answer (score 0):

Return the last node whose index (assuming 1-based indexing) is multiple of *k*.
You can do that by traversing a list and keeping the count of index. If the index happens to the multiple of *k* then store it in `modular_node`. By the time you have traversed the list, your `modular_node` would refer to the *n % k* node from the end. For *n = 19* and *k = 3*, the last node would be at index *18*.

```py
def modular_node_from_end(head):
    modular_node = None
    index_cnt = 1
    while head is not None:
        if index_cnt % k == 0:
            modular_node = head
        head = head.link
        index_cnt += 1
    return mouduar_node.val
```